# Determine what value used in Editor.OnCreateFeature

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

How can I determine what Value-Layer (not the layer itself, but the different colors for different attributes) was used in ArcGIS CreateFeature Event, when I insert a new feature using the Editor?

Comment: Would help people if you state what version of arcgis you are using as there was a siesmic shift in the editor with the release of version 10.0

Comment: I am sorry... I am using ArcGis 10

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Interface **IEditTemplate** you can gain access to this via the **IEditor3** Interface